# Joi Validation: User Name Must NOT Be An Email Address

Tags: javascript, validation, joi

Is there any way to do this by negating Joi's built-in email() validator?

Something like this pseudocode:

```
username: Joi.string().not.Joi.email()
```

OR

```
username: Joi.string().Joi.email().invert()
```

I was able to make it work with the following **Regex**:

```
const emailRegEx = RegExp('^\\w+([\\.-]?\\w+)*@\\w+([\\.-]?\\w+)*(\\.\\w{2,3})+$');
const schema2 = Joi.object({
     username: Joi.string().regex(emailRegEx, { invert: true })
 })
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this would be the best way to do it, but you can try this:

```
const schema = Joi.object().keys({
    username: Joi.alternatives().when(
        Joi.string().email(),
        {
            then: Joi.forbidden().error(new Error('must not be an email')),
            otherwise: Joi.string().required()
        }
     )
});

schema.validate({ username: 'whatever' }); // error: null, value: { username: 'whatever' }

schema.validate({ username: 'my@email.com' }); // error: Error: must not be an email
```